# How can I build customized regression models for different categories in the same python dataframe?

Tags: python, model, categories

I have a data frame in python with the following features:

- country
- age
- weight
- height

I want to predict the "height" using "age" and "weight", but I would like to build a customized model for each country. Is there a way to do that without writing separate code for each country?
Thank you.